# How to make IMemoryCache available in all controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2

It is using Dependency Injection to make `IMemoryCache` available in specific controller only for example

```
public class TController : ControllerBase
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public TController(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public IActionResult GetAccessToken()
    {

        string key ="IDGKey";
        string obj;
        if (!cache.TryGetValue<string>(key, out obj))
        {
            obj = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            _cache.Set<string>(key, obj);
        }
        return obj;

    }
}
```

Now if I try to access `_cache` value in same namespace or in different controller

```
public class RController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult R()
    {
        var cb = _cache.Get("IDGKey");
        return Ok(cb);
    }
}
```

It is giving the following error -

> The name '_cache' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

How can I make it _cache avilable to all controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to define some base controller class that uses `IMemoryCache`

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    protected IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public MyBaseController(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
}
```

Then inherit your controllers from it and don't forget to call base class constructor to instantiate `IMemoryCache`

```
public class MyController : MyBaseController
{
    public MyController(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache): base(configuration, memoryCache)
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Action()
    {
        var value = _memoryCache.Get("some key");
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is giving me error `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'memoryCache' of 'TokensController.TokensController(IMemoryCache)' (CS7036)`

Comment: @JKLM Could you please share the code of `TokensController`? Via [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/).

Comment: @JKLM Unfortunately I cannot see where you use my answer in your code